# How do I get multiple JSON objects from api call?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an API call to the GitLab API to get the projects that are available to a particular user.

I can get one project of an index of my choosing, put it into a ProjectModel with the projectId and the projectName but I can not figure out how to get all of them into an array of ProjectModels.

By printing then I can see them all being printed in the console but it will not let me append them to an array.

It is in the parseJSON function that I am trying to get a hold of all of the projects.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**This is my manager to fetch the projects:**

```
protocol FetchProjectsManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateProjects(_ fetchProjectsManager: FetchProjectsManager, project: ProjectModel?)
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}

struct FetchProjectsManager {

    let projectsURL = "secret"

    var delegate: FetchProjectsManagerDelegate?

    func fetchProjects(privateToken: String) {
        let privateTokenString = "\(projectsURL)projects?private_token=\(privateToken)"
        performRequest(with: privateTokenString)
    }

    func performRequest(with privateTokenString: String) {
        // Create url
        if let url = URL(string: privateTokenString) {
            // Create URLSession
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            // Give the session a task
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }

                if let safeData = data {
                    if let project = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                        self.delegate?.didUpdateProjects(self, project: project)
                    }
                }
            }

            // Start the task
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func parseJSON(_ projectData: Data) -> ProjectModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode([Project].self, from: projectData)

            for project in decodedData {
                print(project)
            }
            let projectId = decodedData[0].id
            let projectName = decodedData[0].name
            let project = ProjectModel(projectId: projectId, projectName: projectName)
            return project

        } catch {
            delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my project model**

```
struct ProjectModel {
    let projectId: Int
    let projectName: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `parseJson` method only returns a single project instead of all of them, change it to

```
func parseJSON(_ projectData: Data) -> [ProjectModel]? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode([Project].self, from: projectData)

        let projects = decodedData.map { ProjectModel(projectId: $0.id,
                                                      projectName: $0.name) }
        return projects

    } catch {
        delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

and you of course need to update `didUpdateProjects` so that it takes an array of  `ProjectModel` or call it in a loop